# troubles while redirecting stderr in csh

Tags: perl, shell, redirect, csh, tcsh

I'm writing a Perl script that should execute commands in shell and parse their output. As a shell I'm intended to use csh. I've started with this

```
my $out = `cmd`
```

but it doesn't capture STDERR, which I need too. Running sh with output redirection does nothing

```
my $out = `sh -c "cmd 2>&1"`
```

still captures only STDOUT, not STDERR.

Even redirecting to file in csh doesn't work for me

```
tcsh$ cmd >& logfile.log
```

still captures STDOUT only %)

The command I'm trying to execute is actuallty sh script and some commands in this script print into STDERR and I want to capture that output. If I execute `sh -c "cmd 2>/dev/null"` STDERR actually goes to /dev/null and only STDOUT is printed in terminal.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I've tried to run sh shell and execute `cmd 2>logfile.log` but `logfile.log` is empty even in this case. I suspect that tcsh is not the main problem here

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is something you are not telling us.  Are you on cygwin? Or Windows?  Do you have a `PERL5SHELL` environment variable set?

There is something that you are not telling us because both of these work fine on the five platforms I can easily test on:

```
% perl -le '$out = `sh -c "grep missing /dev/nowhere 2>&1" | cat -n`; chomp $out; print "got <<<$out>>>"'
got <<<     1   grep: /dev/nowhere: No such file or directory>>>
```

But in far, there is no reason to call *sh*(1) explicitly for shelling out. That’s because Perl **always** calls *sh*(1) for all its backtick, pipe opens, and `system()` shell-outs:

```
% perl -le '$out = `grep missing /dev/nowhere 2>&1 | cat -n`; chomp $out; print "got <<<$out>>>"'
got <<<     1   grep: /dev/nowhere: No such file or directory>>>
```

The only except to this I can think of occurs on non-Unix systems, where because they have no */bin/sh*, something else is defined.

But under no circumstances will simple shell-outs be calling *tcsh*(1) behind your back. You’d’ve had to’ve seriously hacked the *perl*(1) source to get that to happen. I also rather doubt you could (easily) hack the binary, since the string `"/bin/tcsh"` is going to be longer than `"/bin/sh"`, and it isn’t very often going to be found in */bin/* anyway.

That you can’t get stderr redirection working even from the shell says something pretty weird is going on.  I think we need more information.

Comment: Hello @tchrist, I'm on Linux, SuSE Desktop 11. I've just found that STDERR and tcsh doesn't matter here... Both of your examples work fine. But if I put my `cmd` instead of `grep` - it prints nothing. So it seems that `cmd` puts its output not into STDERR or STDOUT. But where elese? /dev/tty probably?

Comment: @marvin: I suppose that’s possible. You can find out by by running it in a cron(1) job. If it is writing to /dev/tty, it is possible to still capture it, but rather a pain in the butt to do so.

Comment: Run 'strace cmd ...' and it will show you exactly what it is writing to (if its not STDERR and STDOUT).

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are capturing the STDOUT of `sh`, which is not the STDERR of `cmd`:

```
my $out = `sh -c "cmd 2>&1"`;
```

Can you just run `cmd` directly?

```
my $out = `cmd 2>&1`;
```

Comment: won't it run cmd in csh shell? if so, csh doesn't support `2>&1` syntax

Comment: cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null should do it - just STDERR and nothing else

Comment: Also I thought that `cmd 2>&1` should redirect STDERR of `cmd` to STDOUT of `sh` which is than captured by perl. Isn't is so?

Comment: @Ingo, it print STDERR in terminal if I run it as `tcsh$ sh -c "cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null"` but returns empty string in Perl: `my $out = \`sh -c "cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null"\``

Comment: How to you manage to get `perl` to invoke `csh` in the first place?

Comment: Then cmd itself redirects STDERR - probably to /dev/tty?

Comment: @reinierpost csh is my working shell ($SHELL) so I run Perl from it

Comment: @reinierpost the script that I'm trying to execute is rc-script for NTP daemon if it could help in any way..

Comment: Well, you can always create a `/bin/sh` script that just says `exec "$@" 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

- Backquotes capture STDOUT not STDERR.
- [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) will dump both stdout and stderr to their parent's settings.
- If you want to *capture* STDERR, you need something like [`IPC::Open3`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aOpen3):

> Extremely similar to [open2()](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aOpen2), [open3()](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aOpen3) spawns the given $cmd and connects CHLD_OUT for reading from the child, CHLD_IN for writing to the child, and CHLD_ERR for errors. If CHLD_ERR is false,

Comment: Extremely similar to a Question that is Asked Frequently, perldoc -q stderr "How can I capture STDERR from an external command?" :-)

Answer (score 1):

You said that running the command `cmd >& logfile.log` in tcsh sends only cmd's stdout to the log file, not its stderr.  That doesn't make sense.

Try replacing cmd with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo stdout
echo STDERR 1>&2
```

Both "stdout" and "STDERR" should show up in logfile.log.

If so, then perhaps your "cmd" is doing something odd.  My best guess is that cmd is writing to /dev/tty, not to either stdout or stderr; that wouldn't be affected by redirection.

To see what I mean, add this line to the above script:

```
echo tty > /dev/tty
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have time to mock up an example as I normally would, nor even test one. I am thinking that you might try using [`Capture::Tiny`](http://p3rl.org/Capture%3a%3aTiny) to see if that helps.